# Como puedo poner un valor a self.titulo, self.autor y self.editorial con input

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

No me aparece este código input("¿Quiere buscar por libro, autor o editorial? ") y me aparece los valores de self.titulo, self.autor y self.editorial. Quiero que al poner el primer código pueda editar el valor de self.titulo, self.autor y self.editorial, así pueda tipear el valor que quiera ponerle a self.titulo. Además que al poner el valor de self.titulo me aparezca el diccionario de libros y con toda su información del diccionario, como también los demás códigos como self.autor y self.editorial.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá dejo el código:

```
#!C:\python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

class Libro:
  def __init__(self, titulo, autor, editorial, paginas_totales, paginas_leidas):
    self.titulo = titulo
    self.autor = autor
    self.editorial = editorial
    self.paginas_totales = paginas_totales
    self.paginas_leidas = paginas_leidas

  def libros(self):
    padre_rico_padre_pobre = {"Autor": "Mario Kasnet", "Editorial": "Cabañita", "Paginas Totales": "163"}
    cien_año_soledad = {"Autor": "Mario Vargas", "Editorial": "Los Laureles", "Paginas Totales": "245"}    
    planta_lima_limon = {"Autor": "Mario Vargas", "Editorial": "Cabañita", "Paginas Totales": "133"}

    if self.titulo == "Padre rico y padre pobre":
     for concepto in padre_rico_padre_pobre:
       print(concepto + ": " + padre_rico_padre_pobre[concepto])
     
    elif self.titulo == "Cien años de soledad":
      for concepto1 in cien_año_soledad:
        print(concepto1 + ": " + cien_año_soledad[concepto1])

    elif self.titulo == "Planta lima limon":
     for concepto2 in planta_lima_limon:
       print(concepto2 + ": " + planta_lima_limon[concepto2])
    else:
      print("El libro no se encuentra")

  def autor(self):
    mario_Kasnet = {"Titulo": "Padre rico y padre pobre", "Editorial": "Cabañita", "Paginas Totales": "163"}
    mario_vargas = {"Titulo": "Cien años de soledad", "Editorial": "Los Laureles", "Paginas Totales": "245"}, {"Titulo": "Planta lima limon", "Autor": "Mario Vargas", "Editorial": "Cabañita", "Paginas Totales": "133"}
    
    if self.autor == "mario kasnet":
     for concepto in mario_kasnet:
       print(concepto + ": " + mario_kasnet[concepto]) 

    elif self.autor == "mario vargas":
     for concepto1 in mario_vargas:
       print(concepto1 + ": " + mario_vargas[concepto1])

  def editorial(self):
    cabañita = {"Titulo": "Padre rico y padre pobre", "Autor": "Mario Kasnet", "Paginas Totales": "163"}, {"Titulo": "Planta lima limon", "Autor": "Mario Vargas", "Paginas Totales": "133"}
    los_laureles = {"Titulo": "Cien años de soledad", "Paginas Totales": "245"}

    if self.autor == "cabañita":
     for concepto in cabañita:
       print(concepto + ": " + cabañita[concepto])

    elif self.autor == "los laureles":
     for concepto1 in los_laureles:
       print(concepto1 + ": " + los_laureles[concepto1])

class Biblioteca(Libro):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__("", "", "", 0, 5)

  def busquedad(self):
    self.titulo = (input("¿Que libro buscas? "))
    self.autor = (input("¿Que autor buscas? "))
    self.editorial = (input("¿Que editorial buscas? "))

    anonimo = (input("¿Quiere buscar por libro, autor o editorial? "))
    print(anonimo)
    if anonimo == "libro":
     print(self.titulo)
    elif anonimo == "autor":
     print(self.autor)
    elif anonimo == "editorial":
     print(self.editorial)

datos_libro = Biblioteca()

datos_libro.busquedad()

datos_libro.libros()

datos_libro.autor()

datos_libro.editorial()

input()
```

Comment: Hmmm, ya tuvimos una pregunta sospechosamente similar más temprano. Me parece que alguien está queriendo que le hagamos la tarea... igualmente voy a tratar de ayudarte.

Comment: Uhh mal ahí, así no se aprende amigo.

Comment: Claro, cada función es independiente. Cuando termina de ejecutarse `libro0` la ejecución no salta a `libro1`. Esto no es como una cláusula `switch`. Tal vez ese era el origen de tu confusión y por eso pusiste los `break` antes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error fue que pusiste el if adentro del for y no afuera en libro3, por eso te tiraba "El libro no se encuentra" 3 veces.

```
def libro3(self):
    planta_lima_limon = {"Autor": "Pedro Suarez", "Editorial": "Los Nenes", "Paginas Totales": "133"}
    if self.titulo == "Planta lima limon":
      for concepto2 in planta_lima_limon:
        print(concepto2 + ": " + planta_lima_limon[concepto2])
    else:
      print("El libro no se encuentra")
```

Comment: No funciona .-.

Comment: @nekordemon ¿En qué sentido no te funciona?

Comment: ahora el codigo no me funciona

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta con el nuevo código y el error

Comment: ok lo hare esta vez

Comment: ya lo cambie el codigo

Comment: @nekordemon Como indica el error, solo puedes usar break dentro de un bucle. Borra los break, igual no hacían nada.

Comment: borro el break y el else ?

Comment: Ahora me aparece una vez .-.

Comment: @nekordemon Claro. Si no quieres que se imprima en lo absoluto entonces no puedes separar la búsqueda en 3 funciones distintas. Porque cómo podría cada función saber si alguna de las otras ya "encontró" el libro? En general no entiendo la idea de separar en 3 funciones distintas

Comment: Pero si quieres una solución no muy buena pero que funciona puedes usar una variable global que empieza siendo False y cambia a True cuando una de las funciones "encuentra" el libro. Y al final, después de llamar a libro3() tendrías que revisar si esa variable está en false y ahí imprimir que no se encontró

Comment: ya lo solucione puse una cuarta, donde sale el "El libro no se encuentra", cuando no pones nada o te equivocas de libro. Lo pongo porque al encontrar el nombre de libro en una función, me sale el diccionario del libro1 y si la función sale el libro 2, me sale el diccionario del libro2.

Comment: Ahora no puedo hacer que el titulo que busco se repita otra vez, en la segunda linea

Comment: Osea, quieres que luego de ingresar el titulo a buscar, te lo repita inmediatamente?

Comment: No quiero que lo repita, quiero que vaya directo a la impresión del diccionario.

Comment: Sigo sin entender xd

Comment: Ya lo modifique la pregunta, con la consulta que me falta